# Escape a hypen in JSON response from Mule

Tags: json, escaping, mule, anypoint-studio

I am using Anypoint Studio 6.1 and Mule 3.8.1 and have the following JSON response from a Mule workflow:

```
{
    "Description": "Top 10 games:
- Mario Kart
- Legend of Zelda"
}
```

This fails validation with the following error:

```
Error: Parse error on line 2:

    {   "Description": "Top 10 games: -     M
    -----------------^
    Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '[', got 'undefined'
```

I have tried escaping the special characters put it still does not work.  How can I change the response to pass JSON v4 validation.  The JSON validator I have been using is http://jsonlint.com/

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The root cause of the issue is carriage return in the JSON response. The valid JSON should be as below

```
{
  "Description": "Top 10 games:\r\n- Mario Kart\r\n- Legend of Zelda"
}
```

Please provide more details on where you are receiving this description. is it from XML or any other source. Also it will be helpful if you post your DWL code as well.